# prisma Order by relation has only _count property. Can not order by relation fields

Tags: sql, postgresql, prisma, prisma2

consider following Prisma schema:

```
model Conversation {
  id           Int                         @id @default(autoincrement())
  createdAt    DateTime                    @db.Timestamp(6)
  messages     ConversationMessage[]
}

model ConversationMessage {
  id             Int                     @id @default(autoincrement())
  text           String                  @db.VarChar(1000)
  sentAt         DateTime                @map("sent_at") @db.Timestamp(6)
  conversationId Int?                    @map("conversation_id")
  userId         Int?                    @map("user_id")
  conversation   Conversation?           @relation(fields: [conversationId], references: [id])
  sender         User?                   @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id])
}
```

I want to run such query so that I get a list of conversations ordered by date of their messages, i.e. the ones with new messages first.

```
prisma.conversation.findMany({
    orderBy: {
        messages: {
            sentAt: 'desc'
        }
    },
    ...
})
```

But the only way that I can query now is like this, i.e. relation has only `_count` property somehow.

```
prisma.conversation.findMany({
    orderBy: {
        messages: {
           '_count': 'desc'
        }
     },
     ...
})
```

Environment & setup

```
    OS: Mac OS,
    Database: PostgreSQL
    Node.js version: v12.19.0
```

Prisma Version

```
prisma               : 2.24.1
@prisma/client       : 2.24.1
Current platform     : darwin
Query Engine         : query-engine 18095475d5ee64536e2f93995e48ad800737a9e4 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/query-engine-darwin)
Migration Engine     : migration-engine-cli 18095475d5ee64536e2f93995e48ad800737a9e4 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/migration-engine-darwin)
Introspection Engine : introspection-core 18095475d5ee64536e2f93995e48ad800737a9e4 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/introspection-engine-darwin)
Format Binary        : prisma-fmt 18095475d5ee64536e2f93995e48ad800737a9e4 (at node_modules/@prisma/engines/prisma-fmt-darwin)
Default Engines Hash : 18095475d5ee64536e2f93995e48ad800737a9e4
Studio               : 0.397.0
Preview Features     : orderByRelation
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

While Prisma V2.19 introduced [sort by relation aggregate value](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting#sort-by-relation-aggregate-value-preview), as of this writing, the only aggregate property supported is `count`. To the best of my knowledge, what you are asking for is not directly supported by Prisma at the moment. It would be possible if they add `min` and `max` aggregate properties for sorting.

A possible workaround is to sort the messages inside Node.js after retrieval. I'm adding a solution that uses the `orderByRelation` preview feature to simplify the sorting and ensure the messages in a conversation are always ordered (newest first).

#### Updating Prisma Client to use `orderByRelation` preview feature.

First, update `schema.prisma` to add the preview feature

```
generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["orderByRelation"]
}
```

Now update the prisma client

```
prisma generate client
```

#### Get `conversations` and sort them by most recent message

```js
// Assuming inside an async function 

let unsortedConversations = await prisma.conversation.findMany({
    include: {
        messages: {
            orderBy: {    
                sentAt: 'desc'  // messages for each converastion will be ordered newest first. 
            }
        }
    },
    // other conditions
})
```

`unsortedConversations` contains all required conversations, but they are unordered. You can sort it in the desired order by creating a custom comparator function.

```js
function conversationComparatorFunction(conversationA, conversationB) {
    // Conversations with 0 messages will be placed last in arbitrary order. 
    if (!conversationB.messages.length) return 1;  
    if (!conversationA.messages.length) return -1;
    
    // sort conversations based on sentAt date of the first message. 
    // since messages were previously sorted, messages[0] always contain the most recent message. 
    if (conversationA.messages[0].sentAt > conversationB.messages[0].sentAt) {
        return -1;
    } else if (conversationA.messages[0].sentAt < conversationB.messages[0].sentAt) {
        return 1;
    } else return 0;

}

let sortedConversations = unsortedConversations.sort(conversationComparatorFunction)
```

Be warned though, if the number of `Conversation` records is *very* large sorting on the application side could lead to poor performance, especially considering Node.js is single-threaded.

Comment: Thanks! I resolved this similarly, but added sorting on the client.

Comment: Sad that this is still not supported :(

Answer (score 0):

A simple answer to this that doesn't use other packages, is to create a property:

`lastChildUpdatedAt` PS: name this as you want

When creating a new child, or updating one, updated this property on the parent too. Then, when fetching, use:

```
orderBy: {
  lastChildUpdatedAt: "desc",
}
```

Answer (score -5):

OrderBy relation is still a preview feature - you need to make sure to use the feature flag

```
generator client {
  provider        = "prisma-client-js"
  previewFeatures = ["orderByRelation"]
}
```

https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-client/filtering-and-sorting#sort-by-relation-preview